# How to provide Internet Access to Private Subnet

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2, internet, vmware-workstation

I really need some help/advise on a networking issue I have. I am fairly new to this sort of configuration so any help would be very much appreciated.

My Setup:

I am using VMWare Workstation 9 to setup a virtual environment for Demo Purposes. I have 2 VM's (Win 2008 R2, CentOS). My Win2008R2 VM is my Domain Controller/DNS/DHCP. It also has Active Directory and LDAP over SSL setup (so my CentOS) box can connect to it.

My CentOS box is running a Mobile Device Management System.

My Problem:

In order to get the setup I want, I needed to create a custom network (Using VM Network Editor) with a 172.x.x.x address (so my DC could be the DNS and DHCP). So both my VM's have a 172 address, which is great!

However, I would really like to have it so these VM's have Internet access as well, but I am completely stumped on how I would go about achieving this (this being because I am a noobie to all of this). I have looked around and by the sounds of things, I would need to add a second NIC to my DC and then somehow configure the DNS so my CentOS VM would get Internet Access through the DC.

Just to note: My CentOS box is on the same subnet as my DC, but is NOT domain joined.

Could someone please help me with any advise/tutorials/walkthrough/answers etc. I would really appreciate it!

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Is your Domain Controller connected to the internet currently?

Comment: Yes it currently has 2 NICs. NIC one is a 172 address which is on my subnet without Internet (same subnet as the CentOS vm) and the second NIC is connected (via Automatically Bridged). I can access the Internet from DC but not the CentOS box. I want Internet on the CentOS box so I can access the Mobile Device Management System being hosted on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup routing on your DC.  This will allow it to route the internet through to your VMs.    There are a gazillion guides on the internet specifically for this.  You are not supposed to do this on the same server as an AD, but on a test server it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks very much, I hate to be annoying but is it possible for you to give me a link to a good one or where I could find one? I really am completely new to this so probably wouldn't know it if I found it. I appreciate the advise, I will seperate my AD from my DNS when it comes to production. I appreciate your advise thanks.